# Netlogo editor for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, netlogo

I see that making a custom editor for Eclipse is quite involved. So before I roll my own editor/plug-in for NetLogo I was wondering if someone else has done it already?

Alternatively, I see the Eclipse editor is quite involved but produces a very complete end product. I mainly want something that's keyword and indentation aware. So inasmuch as that's a simpler project... that will do too.

Finally, links to where I can read up on building one myself will be appreciated.

Mike

Comment: [How do I write an Eclipse editor for my own language?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_an_editor_for_my_own_language%3F)

Comment: If such a thing already existed, it would almost certainly be listed at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/resources.shtml